# PHPexcel Add rows from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I have a form that posts to mysql like this:

[image]

The First 2 entries ( ID and User ) need to go a specific Cell once:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', $row['ID']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', $row['User']);
```

The others ( Date, Unit and Number ) need to post to the row from left to right.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you ask, `$row['ID']` and `$row['User']` has the correct values only inside your loop. You can use a function like `mySetCellsValue(ID,User)` thats update two cells. When you fill the table, you add an event listener that call this function.

Answer (score 1):

```
//some code to get the data from mysql

//teller to know where to start in sql
$teller = 5;
foreach($yourarray as $row){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $teller, $row['ID']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $teller, $row['User']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $teller, $row['Date']); 
    //D - Z?
    $teller++;
}
```

This what u want?